# ON DUPLICATE KEY - doesn't insert, only update

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a script that will update the record in the table when it already exists, or insert a new record when it doesn't exist.
The problem is that my mysql statement can only upload the record but doesn't insert the new one:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO lek_podstawowe(drug_name_pl) VALUES ('$drug_name_pl') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote_sum=vote_sum+'$vote', vote_num=vote_num+1";
```

Here is my table structure:

```
   Field         Type      Null Key Default Extra
    id           int(11)    NO  PRI NULL    
    drug_name_pl varchar(11)NO  UNI NULL    
    drug_img     text       NO      NULL    
    vote_sum     int(11)    NO      NULL    
    vote_num     int(11)    NO      NULL
```

How can I change my statement to accomplish this? Thank you

Comment: Is the id field an auto-increment field?

Comment: yes, please add output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE lek_podstawowe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that id field was not auto-increment. Problem already fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is useful? 
[MySQL REPLACE COMMAND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)